# Getting Started type resources for TFS in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have been dumped in the deep end at a new job and I need to create, administer, and use TFS projects currently in some disarray.  I'm looking for recommendations on good books, tutorials, articles etc. on using TFS as integrated with VS 2010 (and otherwise, but not s priority).

Given that I don't enjoy most beginner oriented and 'for dummies' material, what resources should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This book is from some of the MSFT guys. It is really good.

[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Application-Lifecycle-Management-Programmer/dp/0470484268](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470484268)

Answer (score 1):

Books might give you a pretty decent general background, but my take is Team Foundation Server with Visual Studio 2010 is still a bit of a moving target (i.e. the specific issues in the TFS build that your employer is using may not match the TFS in a published book; you may want to check the configurations of your installations...).  Of course, almost all software starts being updated Scrum-style before the latest update is pushed out to users anymore, but my "moving target" characterization of TFS is probably more appropriate than for the average development tool ... maybe not; it may not matter that much to most people that TFS is still a bit "fluxy" ... [Brian Harry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/) might use a different phrase, but I'm guessing that he would ascribe the TFS "fluxiness" as reflection of his recent pronouncement that **[TFS is open platform](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2010/11/22/tfs-is-an-open-platform.aspx)** with lots of different things going on, lots of different moving pieces.  *We are all open source now!*

If you are a glass-is-half-full kind of a guy like I am, you will see this "moving target fluxiness" as actually sort of a cool thing -- exciting improvements and great new features will be coming your way; you might even get to find new features, help make those improvements happen.  Hopefully, nothing will happen to destroy a project your employer is counting on and sink you any further into the deep end in your new job -- look on the bright side, you may gain a profound sense of empathy for your predecessor before this is all through.  **There are always all kinds of positives in situations like this!**

*If you were a miserable cynic, you'd say that if Boeing built planes like Microsoft builds software, thriving ecosystems of "development" passengers on airliners would have hands-on (i.e. white-knuckle, death-grip) opportunities in every flight -- they would be involved in discovering and improving mechanical, electronic, hydraulic design features or maybe learning about something new related to a supplier issue, a new failure mode, new mfg and maintenance issues.*  Don't be a miserable cynic -- sieze the day; embrace change, you're in the deep end already, you might as well swim to the other side, right?

Since there will be a lot of people at Microsoft serving the MSDN community and trying use/build/tailor/improve the TFS "open platform" (to "eat their dog food," so to speak) you won't really know exactly where the best developments might come from ... I would routinely follow a [search of *all* MSDN blogs for the "Team Foundation Server"](http://blogs.msdn.com/search/SearchResults.aspx?q=%22Team+Foundation+Server%22&sort=date+desc&PageIndex=1) keywords ... in my case, I pasted [this RSS url](http://blogs.msdn.com/search/Searchrss.aspx?q=%22Team+Foundation+Server%22&sort=date+desc) into my RSS reader.

Answer (score 0):

[`Visual Studio 2010 ALM Virtual Machine + Labs: December 2010 Refresh`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/briankel/archive/2010/06/25/now-available-visual-studio-2010-rtm-virtual-machine-with-sample-data-and-hands-on-labs.aspx)